# Is it posisble to have two different inputs that can filter my DT table using shiny R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, rshiny

I have an app that allows me to see the filter the number of cars by using an input.

Here is the code I have.

````
```{r}

selectInput("input_type","Select Cylinder Size: ", c("All", mtcars$cyl))
selectInput("input_type2", "Select # of Gears: ", c("All", mtcars$gear))

mtcars2 <- reactive({
  if(input$input_type=="All")
    mtcars
  else
    subset(mtcars,cyl == input$input_type)
  })


renderDataTable(
  datatable(mtcars2())
  )  

```
````

Although I have a second input that can also let me filter by gears, it doesn't work since I can't figure out how to tie it to the reactive function.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this [untested code]:

```
selectInput("input_type","Select Cylinder Size: ", c("All", mtcars$cyl))
selectInput("input_type2", "Select # of Gears: ", c("All", mtcars$gear))

mtcars2 <- reactive({
  d <- mtcars
  if(input$input_type !="All")
    d <- subset(d, cyl == input$input_type)
  if(input$input_type2 !="All")
    d <- subset(d, gear == input$input_type2)
  d
  })


renderDataTable(
  datatable(mtcars2())
  )
```

By the way, you might want to use `unique` when defining the choices lists for your inputs.

Comment: I want to thank you - this is amazing and perfect.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer - I got stuck on another question and wanted to know if you could help me. Here is the link.  @Limey https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025317/how-to-use-a-value-box-of-two-inputs-using-rshiny-and-rmarkdown-r