# How to use a value box of two inputs using Rshiny and Rmarkdown? R

Tags: r, r-markdown, shinydashboard, shinyapps, rshiny

My goal is to get a value box to update using some inputs I have.

Here is my code

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    graphics: yes
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
library(readr)
library(shiny)
library(knitr)

```
  
  Inputs {.sidebar data-width=300}
=====================================


```{r}
selectInput("input_type","Select Cylinder Size: ", c("All", mtcars$cyl))
selectInput("input_type2", "Select # of Gears: ", c("All", mtcars$gear))

mtcars2 <- reactive({
  d <- mtcars
  if(input$input_type !="All")
    d <- subset(d, cyl == input$input_type)
  if(input$input_type2 !="All")
    d <- subset(d, gear == input$input_type2)
  d
  })



```

# Page 1 

Column {data-width=600}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Table
```{r echo=FALSE}

renderDataTable(
  datatable(mtcars2())
  ) 

```


Column {data-width=300}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Value Box

```{r}
valueBox(0)
```
````

My goal is to get a value box where I can get the sum of hp depending on the remaining data that is filtered.

For example in this screenshot I filtered to only see cars that are 6 cyl and have 3 gears.
My goal would be to see the sum of hp populate on the value box.

[image]

Additional Code

```
renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      mtcars2() %>% summarise(Sum=sum(hp)) %>% pull(Sum) ,
      paste("Total HP:", input$input2)
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
library(dplyr)
```

to your YAML header and then replace

```
valueBox(0)
```

with

```
  renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "Total HP",
      mtcars2() %>% summarise(Sum=sum(hp)) %>% pull(Sum)
    )
  })
```

or similar.

Comment: Thank you Limey, I have one quick additional question. I added to my source code. I'm trying to get the "text" in the value box to update based on the input. Can you take a look and let me know what you think? I am able to get it to work with only one input but cannot get it with two.

Comment: Your code updates as expected for me, but I think you want to reverse the order of the arguments.  `renderValueBox`'s parameters are `value` then `caption`, not `caption` then `value`...

Comment: yes, but it only takes one input - is there a way I can have a if/else logic that shows both inputs? Kind of like how you did it for the data table in my first question? So if someone selects cyl and gear - the sum will consider both inputs.